# Dynamic t-sql quotes in string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following in a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @new_column_name varchar(9)
DECLARE @table_name varchar(16)
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(2000)

SET @new_column_name = N'name'
SET @table_name = N'tbl_test_table'

SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @CountOUT = COUNT(*) FROM [' + @table_name + '] WHERE [' + @new_column_name + '] = ''' + @description + ''''``
```

This works absolutely fine until @description has a single quote in it. In my C# I replace single quotes with two single quotes but this is still causing a problem when creating the above SQL string.

Any ideas how to fix this for:

```
SET @description = N'Adam''s Car'
```

The reason I am using dynamic SQL is because the 'name' column is temporary and only exists during the lifetime of the stored procedure.

Comment: use parameters in your C# ADO.NET code...

Comment: I do unfortunately be to no avail!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NB: See [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL - Dealing with Dynamic Table and Column Names](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#objectnames)

You should still use parameterised sql and use `exec sp_executesql` (that takes parameters). Also use `QUOTENAME` around the object names rather than concatenating the brackets yourself.

```
SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @CountOUT = COUNT(*) FROM ' + 
QUOTENAME(@table_name) + ' WHERE ' + 
QUOTENAME(@new_column_name) + ' = @description'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
    ,N'@description varchar(50), @CountOUT int OUTPUT'
    ,@description = @description
    ,@CountOUT = @CountOUT OUTPUT;
```