# Transact-SQL using variable for table name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have try to use statement below in my SQL. Is it possible by any means to dynamically select table form database. (For example select table name from Comobox and then display data from selected table)

```
SET @var1 = 'test';
SELECT * From @var1
```

Comment: If you need to refer to your tablename by variable, chances are that your design needs rethinking

Answer (score -2):

Dynamic SQL requires that you create a string consisting of the sql statement, and then you execute the string.  [Dynamic t-sql quotes in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500984/dynamic-t-sql-quotes-in-string)

Comment: Thak you for your answer. Can you give me short example.